# Rejecting special values in a 3D array given the indices to reject

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates, mask

I would like to extend a problem I already [discussed on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580252/calculation-on-2d-array-rejecting-special-values-knowing-the-indices). It was dealing with 2D `numpy arrays` and I would like to do the same with a 3-dimensional array.

I have an array of coordinates `coord`, with shape `(3, 4, 2)`, that contains all coordinates for each slice that I want to mask in the data array `Values2`. There are masked values in the coordinate array in order to keep same dimension for each slice.

```
import numpy as np

coord = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 2], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]])
# Some 0-entries are masked values : [[[nan, nan], [nan, nan], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]], [[2, 0], [2, 2], [nan, nan], [nan, nan]], [[2, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]]

Values2 = np.array([[[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[8., 7., 6.],
       [5., 4., 3.],
       [2., 1., 0.]]])
```

If I try a similar approach with the code from the referenced SO question, we have something like that, but it doesn't seem adapted for 3D cases and I don't know how to adapt it myself.

```
i, j = coord.T

mask = np.zeros(Values.shape, bool)
mask[i,j] = True
m = np.ma.array(Values, mask=mask)
```

The desired output from combining the `coord` array  and `Values2` array is:

```
Array_expected = ([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ nan,  1.,  nan]],

       [[ 8.,  7.,  6.],
        [ 5.,  4.,  3.],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan]]])
```

But the `nan` entries should not change the values present in `Values2`.

Comment: Could you show what the expected / desired result is?

Comment: i add the array expected! ;) sorry for the lack of information..

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question is a follow-up on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889946/reshape-of-dtype-object-array-with-a-loop).

You should think of the mask that you got from that question (which is associated with your `coords` array) to be just as applicable to your 3D array. So rather than working with *indices* of elements you want to mask in the array, you should work just with the (boolean) *mask*.

The mask you got from your previous question looked something like:

```
mask = array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False,  True]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

(Which I altered in one dimension, because the dimensions between your previous question and this one don't match up).

Now, just make a new masked array using your `Values2` array:

```
>>> result = np.ma.masked_array(Values2, mask=mask)
>>> result 
masked_array(data =
 [[[0.0 1.0 2.0]
  [3.0 4.0 5.0]
  [6.0 7.0 8.0]]

 [[1.0 1.0 1.0]
  [1.0 1.0 1.0]
  [-- 1.0 --]]

 [[8.0 7.0 6.0]
  [5.0 4.0 3.0]
  [-- -- --]]],
             mask =
 [[[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True False  True]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

If you really don't need the mask, so you want to fill the masked entries, you should use the `filled` method:

```
>>> np.ma.filled(result, np.nan)
array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
        [  6.,   7.,   8.]],

       [[  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [ nan,   1.,  nan]],

       [[  8.,   7.,   6.],
        [  5.,   4.,   3.],
        [ nan,  nan,  nan]]])
```

The documentation on [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) is full of good examples that can help you even further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! ;) yep i agree with you! but the aim is to automated that because of my array have dimensions close to 250x400x100... :) Here it s just a part of my array to have a simple example.

Comment: If it helped, then don't forget to close the question by marking it as "accepted". Also, it might've been better to formulate your *real* question from the start, rather than spreading tidbits over different questions, because anyone who didn't know the coords array had masked entries (an edit you made later), would've been confused and couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by using reshape, certainly not the more efficient but it works :

```
coord2 = coord.reshape((coord.shape[0]*coord.shape[1],2))

i, j = coord2.T

i_reshape = i.reshape((coord.shape[0],coord.shape[1])).T

j_reshape = j.reshape((coord.shape[0],coord.shape[1])).T


mask = np.zeros(Values2.shape, bool)

for i in range(i_reshape.shape[1]):
    mask[i,i_reshape[:,i],j_reshape[:,i]] = True

m = np.ma.array(Values2, mask=mask)
```

And i get :

```
 m
Out[848]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[[-- 1.0 2.0]
  [3.0 4.0 5.0]
  [6.0 7.0 8.0]]

 [[-- 1.0 1.0]
  [1.0 1.0 1.0]
  [-- 1.0 --]]

 [[8.0 7.0 6.0]
  [5.0 4.0 3.0]
  [-- -- --]]],
             mask =
 [[[ True False False]
  [False False False]
  [False False False]]

 [[ True False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True False  True]]

 [[False False False]
  [False False False]
  [ True  True  True]]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: I test the code, it works well without 'nan' but when i used the masked array, i obtain this error : "index (-9223372036854775805) out of range (0<=index<2) in dimension 1"...certainly due to nan... :/

Comment: Please don't add a new question in a comment on an answer on your very own question. Almost no-one will read these comments. If any of the answers solved your problem, you should [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Then, if you have new problems, [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).